# asp.net MVC cascading dropdown lists

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create some cascading dropdown lists in asp.net. The lists are populating correctly on page load:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.CountriesDDL, "CountryCode", "Country"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Region)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Region, new SelectList(Model.RegionsDDL, "CountryCode", "RegionName"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
```

I'm using jQuery/Ajax in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Country").change(function () {
            $("#Region").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRegionsByCountryCode")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { countryCode: $("#Country").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $("#Regions").append('<option value="'
                         + value.CountryCode + '">'
                         + value.RegionName + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve regions.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

That is calling a controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetRegionsByCountryCode(string countryCode)
    {
        var regions = _uiRepository.GetRegionsByCountryCode(countryCode);
        return Json(regions);
    }
```

But when I change a select from the "Country" dropdown, I get a popup dialog that says:

```
Failed to retrieve regions.[object Object]
```

I'm not sure what that error means or how I can debug this. I set a break point on the controller method, but it never hits it?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, press F12 to view the developer tools. Then click on the Console tab. Do you see any errors here when you change the Country select list?

Comment: Your code looks fine(atleast the ajax call part). Can you put a breakpoint in your `GetRegionsByContryCode` action method and see whether it is returning proper data (200 response). You can use your browser's network tab to see the response. Also you can do a console.log inside your error handler (add 3 params and console.log all of them and see what you get)

Comment: @Mahesh Warrier I don't see any errors in the console tab when making changes from the select list. @Shyju I have a break point on the `GetRegionsByCountryCode` action method, but it doesn't seem to hit it when I change selections from the dropdown list?

Comment: Correction, I found the `GetRegionsByCountryCode` in the Network tab of chrome tools. It shows status code of 200 OK.

Comment: The ActionMethod was on a registration page and I needed to add [AllowAnonymous] to the method in the controller. I am now able to hit the breakpoint on the `GetRegionsByCountryCode`. The method appears to be functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drop down id is **`Region`** but in your success function you are using **`Regions`**

Make this one small change and it will work.

**Controller:**

```
public class MyCountry
{
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public int CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<MyCountry> Country { get; set; }
    public List<Region> Region { get; set; }
}

public class DropDownExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ViewModel();

        var c1 = new MyCountry { Country = "South Africa", CountryCode = 1 };
        var c2 = new MyCountry { Country = "Russia", CountryCode = 2 };

        model.Country = new List<MyCountry> { c1, c2 };

        var r1 = new Region { RegionName = "Gauteng", CountryCode = 1};
        var r2 = new Region { RegionName = "Western Cape", CountryCode = 1 };
        var r3 = new Region { RegionName = "Siberia", CountryCode = 2 };

        model.Region = new List<Region> { r1, r2,r3};
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetRegionsByCountryCode(string countryCode)
    {
        var r1 = new Region { RegionName = "Gauteng", CountryCode = 1 };
        var r2 = new Region { RegionName = "Western Cape", CountryCode = 1 };
        var r3 = new Region { RegionName = "Siberia", CountryCode = 2 };

        var regions = new List<Region> { r1, r2, r3 };

        var results = regions.Where(r => r.CountryCode == Int32.Parse(countryCode)).ToList();

        return Json(results);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MVCTutorial.Controllers.ViewModel

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Country").change(function () {

            var countryCode = $("#Country").val();
            $("#Region").empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRegionsByCountryCode")',
                data: { countryCode: countryCode },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $("#Region").append('<option value="'
                                             + value.CountryCode + '">'
                                             + value.RegionName + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve regions.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    Country
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.Country, "CountryCode", "Country"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Region
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Region, new SelectList(Model.Region, "CountryCode", "RegionName"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, your two suggested small changes was all that was needed. Working now! Thank you so much.

Comment: **You needed to add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet to your JSON call. This is wrong !** You do not need to do that for an action method which is decorated with `[HttpPost]` attribute. It is needed only if it is a GET action.

Answer (score 0):

Add contentType:'application/json' in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRegionsByCountryCode")',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType:'application/json'
                data: { countryCode: $("#Country").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $("#Regions").append('<option value="'
                         + value.CountryCode + '">'
                         + value.RegionName + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve regions.' + ex);
                }
            });
```

Comment: That's not necessary at all, and if you were to add it, you would need to also stringify the data.