# Cascaded Drop Down List with search box

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use cascaded Drop Down for a project, but with a bit of a twist. For Power Users, they can enter a stock code and search. The retrieved information then updates the Parent Drop Down and the cascaded Drop Down selection.

Using a click event, I can search the entered value and it returns all the needed information. I can update the Parent to Display the correct information, But unable to get the child to display. It's stuck on showing " -- Select --" Populating the drop down's with data to select from works great. Could really use some insight and help.. Got myself stumped on the child. Thanks..

I followed this example to setup the Dropdowns. [asp.net MVC cascading dropdown lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340962/asp-net-mvc-cascading-dropdown-lists)

```
<Controller>
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["User"] = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            BindPartType();
            return View();
        }
 public void BindPartType()
        {
            partsmanagementEntities5 parttypelist = new partsmanagementEntities5(); //Parts
            var parttype = parttypelist.parttypes.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> pli = new List<SelectListItem>();
            pli.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Catagory--", Value = "0" });
            foreach (var m in parttype)
            {
                pli.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.PartType1, Value = m.idPartType.ToString() });
                ViewBag.PartType = pli;
            }
        }
        public JsonResult GetInventory(int? id)
        {
            partsmanagementEntities5 partlist = new partsmanagementEntities5();
            var ddlpart = partlist.parts.Where(x => x.PartType == id).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> lipart = new List<SelectListItem>();
           lipart.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Inventory--", Value = "0" });
            if (ddlpart != null)
            {
                foreach (var x in ddlpart)
                {
                    lipart.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.PartDescription, Value = x.idParts.ToString() });
                }
            }
            return Json(new SelectList(lipart, "Value", "Text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
        }
 public JsonResult Check(string id)
        {
            partsmanagementEntities5 partlist = new partsmanagementEntities5();
            StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
            if(id != null && id != "")
            {
                foreach (char c in id)
                {
                    if (!char.IsNumber(c))
                        test.Append(c);
                }

                var ddlpartnumber = partlist.parts.Where(x => x.PartNumber == id.ToString());
                PartDetails li = new PartDetails();
                foreach (var item in ddlpartnumber.ToList())
                {
                    li.PartNumber = item.PartNumber;
                    li.PartPrice = item.PartPrice;
                    li.idParts = item.idParts;
                    li.EHF = item.EHF;
                    li.PartDescription = item.PartDescription;
                    li.PartImage = item.PartImage;
                    li.partImageContentType = item.partImageContentType;
                    li.unit = item.unit;
                    li.PartType = item.PartType;
                    li.VendorPartNumber = item.VendorPartNumber;                  
                }
                return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


<View>

<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:0.8ex;padding-top:0.8ex">@Html.Label("Catagory: ")</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartType, ViewBag.PartType as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width: 800px;" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left:6ex;padding-top:0.8ex"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:1px;white-space:nowrap;padding-left:0.8ex">@Html.Label("Inventory:  ")</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartNumber, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Inventory--", new { style = "width:900px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:1px;white-space:nowrap;padding-left:6ex">@Html.Label("Or choose:")</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:1px;white-space:nowrap;padding-left:0.8ex">@Html.Label("Enter Valid Part #:  ")</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="CheckPartNumber" id="CheckPartNumber">  <input type="button" id="Search" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </tr>
                </table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PartType").change(function () {
            $("#PartNumber").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetInventory", "partrequests")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#PartType").val() },
                success: function (PartNumber) {
                    $.each(PartNumber, function (i, PartNumber) {
                        $("#PartNumber").append('<option value="'
                                                   + PartNumber.Value + '">'
                                             + PartNumber.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });

$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Search").click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Check","partrequests")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#CheckPartNumber").val() },
                success: function (Data) {
                var selectedValue = Data.PartType
                $('#PartType option').map(function () {
                 if ($(this).val() == selectedValue) return this;
                }).attr('selected', 'selected').change();
                var selectedValue2 = Data.idParts;
                $('#PartNumber option').map(function () {
                 if ($(this).val() == selectedValue2) return this;
                }).attr('selected', 'selected');
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It probably hasn't populated in the DOM yet so it's not selected. You need to .trigger('change') not call it like change() - make sure you select it, then in another statement trigger change, so it actually did change in the dom.

Comment: @ Nikki9696 Never thought of it that way. Can you show how you would change it? Thanks..

Comment: basically the code you have, just take apart the chain and set the selected attribute on the element, and then call {yourelement}.trigger('change') so that the child element populates based off its choice (I'm assuming you want the child options to be based off the parent)

Comment: I think I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. I started copying this into a little test project so I could give a full answer as an example, then I see that this function only returns a single item and got a little confused. Are these dropdowns going to already be populated? Can we see your controller code if you need more help please, so I can create a full test?

Comment: @ Nikki9696 Sorry, I only included the check details action from the controller and the script that retrieves the part details. What I'm trying to do is incorporate a search feature where if you know the part number already, you can type that in and retrieve the info. But What I'm wanting it to do is have the dropdowns reflect the results.  I can change the parent dropdown that contains the Part Category, It's the actual Part Selection that doesn't want to take the change.

Comment: Added more of my code to try and clear some confusion.. Hope it helps..

Comment: What is "selectedvalue2"? if ($(this).val() == selectedValue2)

Comment: also, $('#PartType option').map(function () {
                 if ($(this).val() == selectedValue) return this;
                }).attr('selected', 'selected').trigger('change');  - note that this may require a promise or something because it takes time to roundtrip to a server before the option is available in the next list to be selected

Comment: @ Nikki9696  Sorry, didn't notice that I had missed this... var selectedValue2 = Data.idParts;

Comment: @Nikki9696 Have to apologize, Was made to take holidays.. Any ideas on this? Thanks.